# Can't detect SSD when installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside with Windows

Tags: boot, 16.04, partitioning, system-installation, raid

I recently tried to install Ubuntu on my razer blade pro, which has two **raid0** configured SSD, I can successfully boot into Ubuntu live session with a USB stick, but when I tried to install it on the laptop, I found the Ubuntu can't detect the SSD in the laptop at all, it's empty in the installation type choosing page where it supposed to list my partitions on the SSD (I shrank 50G space for Ubuntu in Windows non allocated, I directly get to the second "Installation type" window with the list of device on which I could install Ubuntu. And there I only got one device named /dev/sda(with nothing after it)). Later I tried to use GPart tool in Ubuntu to partition, but there's nothing as well, only my USB stick is listed there. I think it's probably a setting problem(Everything is fine in Windows), probably have something to do with raid0, so please help a little if you can, thanks.

Comment: Have you had any luck? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately no :( I was thinking maybe this kind of serious issue was solved by other people long time ago, but I'm wrong..

Comment: as a matter of fact, after a long ass night i got it working on my new RBP. will post an answer in a bit

Comment: Wow, that's great, please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres what I did to get it to work:

- Open the BIOS

  - Disable **RAID0** in the `Advanced` menu
  - Set **SATA Mode Selection** to **AHCI** in `Chipset` -> `SATA And RST Configuration` menu
  - Set **Secure Boot** to **Disabled** in `Security` menu
  - Set **Boot option filter** to **UEFI and Legacy** in `Boot` -> `Launch CSM` menu

From here it should be able to see the SSDs.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!but now I can't see my Windows partitions, are they wiped and do I need to reinstall my Windows then (glad I made a backup a few days earlier)

Comment: Yes you will need to reinstall Windows! removing the RAID0 config wiped everything from the drive